# Google Shopping & Adwords GCLID

Tags: google-ads-api, google-shopping

Is there a way to tell the difference between a Google Adword referral and a Google Shopping referral purely from the URL?

I can see a gclid from both:

```
?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8rv7ufSh1gIVBirTCh3FlwWHEAkYASABEgK7IPD_BwE (shopping)
?gclid=COuE-5v1odYCFYqU7QodIeEHnA (adwords)
```

Is there a formula to this or are they entirely random?